# where women allowed to work in Hinduism

Tags: women

Are their mention of women doing work and also helping provide for the family in Hindu text? If so please give scriptural refrences. Also I know Indian society was a patriarchy which I don't see really as a bad I just wnat to know what women could do in it.

Comment: Women are some of the best sages and goddesses in Hinduism.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha I mean in terms of ordinary women were they allowed to make money ie be blacksmiths, carpenters or even mentions of such.

Comment: If a women can do, then let her do, what Hinduism would have to say regarding that?

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha this isn't about oh if scripture says let her do i am just curious and wish to know.

Comment: I wanna see what the society was liked, because I am getting mixed messages in scriptures which is good. Shows diverse range of thoughts.

Comment: Scriptures are made to enlighten people and provide knowledge to them. They aren't rule books or jail rules that'd let them enlightenment.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha I hope you understand I am not and cannot gate keep anyone from getting a job I am just curious if such is mentioned in Indian text if not please stop commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Indian society was a patriarchy

What one does and what scripture says shouldn't be mixed together as IPC doesn't allow rape, murder etc. But if someone does it, then person is responsible not IPC

***What scripture says about the topic***

From manusmriti

> ***The wife must be given the responsibility by the husband of collecting and spending his wealth, engaged in maintaining cleanliness
> of the household, of fulfilling the religious obligations, of
> preparing the food. (Manu 9;11.)***
>
> Those deluded relatives who live off a woman’s property — her
> carriages, her clothes, and so on are evil and go to hell. (Manu 3:52)
>
> A ***son is even (as) oneself, (such) a daughter is equal to a son***;
> how can another (heir) take the estate, while such (an appointed
> daughter who is even) oneself, lives? (Manu 9:130.)

Women in war

[Yajurveda 17.45](https://vedicscriptures.in/yajurveda/17/45)

O Brave Women, obtain training in martial arts & warfare. Unleash your potential and destroy the enemies. capture them and do not mercy on those who spread hatred and vices in society. imprison them.

*You may find some anti women verses in hinduism chances are they could be prakshipt (later interpolation)
Or
reject it under manu 4.176*

He shall, avoid such wealth and pleasures as are opposed to righteousness, as also righteousness if it be conducive to unhappiness, or disapproved by the people.—(176)

Comment: I think verses equally praise and criticize, so..

Comment: @Haridasa ok, but do what you like as manu 4.176

Comment: Can you link verses for Manu as well based on authentic sources? :)

Comment: https://archive.org/details/vishuddha-manusmriti-dr.-surendra-kumar  most authentic manusmriti but you don't know hindi

Comment: I think smrutis should not be considered main sources. especially manusmriti which is known to have been changed and interpolated with commentaries and opinions of the writers rather than the original content

Comment: @subject-q says who? Maybe people just don't understand the Smirti.

Comment: @Hope verse 9.11 is in regards to accounting not making work.